# Can we create a custom policy in azure to prevent the deletion of the resources in a subscription?

Tags: azure, azure-policy

I know we can apply locks to the subscription level, but applying locks will prevent you from revoking the IAM role, so I would like to know if we can have a custom policy to avoid the deletion?

Answer (score 2):

no, because deletion is allowed by granting an action called `write` over the resource\scope, so if you would create a policy that prohibits that, you would lose ability to edit resources, as there is no way for the you to specify deletes only.

locks are meant for that

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft now has a [DenyAction](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/governance/policy/concepts/effects#denyaction-preview) for Azure Policy in preview. This means you can now setup a policy definition and assignments that will prevent deletion of the resources you specify regardless of the roles.

Here's also a link to the [initial announcement](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/azure-governance-and-management/prevent-accidental-deletions-at-scale-using-azure-policy/ba-p/3689186) in late December 2022.

Comment: I have also tried to create azure policy definition but its not allowing DenyAction.

{
  "mode": "All",
  "policyRule": {
    "if": {
      "allOf": [
        {
          "field": "type",
          "equals": "Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/subnets"
        },
        {
          "field": "name",
          "contains": "reserved"
        }
      ]
    },
    then: {
        effect: 'DenyAction'
        details: {
          actionNames: ['Delete']
        }
      }
 }
}